# how to remove all [number] in text file (from wikipedia)?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove all `[Numbers]` in a file. I am using notepad++.
content of my file is from Wikipedia.

for example :

Part of the content of my file:

---

General features include:**[6]**

Tabbed document interface **[7]**

Source code editing features include:**[6]**

Notepad++ supports syntax highlighting and code folding for over 50 programming, scripting, and markup languages.**[6][8]**

how can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a regex replace
Find: `\[[0-9]+\]`
Replace with nothing

Answer (score 3):

type into search field: `\[\d+\]`

check the Regular Expression checkbox in the lower section of the dialog box.
A very cool site for testing your regex:
http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: This is the more proper answer because of its specificity toward Notepad++ (And using `\d` makes it prettier).  No offense, Steve.  ^_^